# Add Group to Folder in a Document Library using Powershell

Tags: powershell, permissions, groups, folder

I want to create a Function with a single command line to add a SP Group to a Folder within a Documents Library.

Structure:

- Site

  - Document Library

    - Folder (*Permissions/Group(s) to be added here*)

      - Items (*Documents*)

I have...

```
function Add-SPPermissionToListGroup
{
param ($Url, $ListName, $GroupName, $PermissionLevel)
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity $Url
$list = $web.Lists.TryGetList($ListName)
if ($list -ne $null)
{
    if ($list.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $False)
    {
        $list.BreakRoleInheritance($True)
    }
    else
    {
        if ($web.SiteGroups[$GroupName] -ne $null)
        {
            $group = $web.SiteGroups[$GroupName]
            $roleAssignment = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($group)
            $roleDefinition = $web.RoleDefinitions[$PermissionLevel];
            $roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($roleDefinition);
            $list.RoleAssignments.Add($roleAssignment)
            $list.Update();
            Write-Host "Successfully added $PermissionLevel permission to $GroupName group in $ListName list. " -foregroundcolor Green
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Host "Group $GroupName does not exist." -foregroundcolor Red
        }
    }
}
$web.Dispose()
}
```

...which I got from [Add group to Library permissions using powershell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58293/add-group-to-library-permissions-using-powershell)

Q:
How do I modify the above to get what I need?
I have tried a few things but no success.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to change is the object where you add new role assignment, in you case: - change list to folder. Your modified script:

```
function Add-SPPermissionToFolderGroup
{
    param ($Url, $sourceFolder, $GroupName, $PermissionLevel)
    $web = Get-SPWeb -Identity $Url

            // $sourceFolderGets the folder that is located at the specified URL.
            $folder = $web.GetFolder($sourceFolder)
            $group = $web.SiteGroups[$GroupName]
            $roleAssignment = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($group)
            $roleDefinition = $web.RoleDefinitions[$PermissionLevel];
            $roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($roleDefinition);

            // break role inheritance for folders/files because they will be having permissions separate from their parent file/folder
            $folder.Item.BreakRoleInheritance($true);

            // apply the new roleassignment to the folder.  You can do this at the listitem level if desired (i.e. this could be SPfile.Item.... instead of SPFolder.Item)
            $folder.Item.RoleAssignments.Add($roleAssignment);
            $folder.Item.Update();
    $web.Dispose()
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Thank you, Thank you!!! Figured it out. Tried to put the full path in the url and didn't work then tried to add the path after the domain in front of the foldername (sourcefolder) and that worked 100%. :)

Comment: FYI: ur missing the $ by ($true) - $folder.Item.BreakRoleInheritance(true);

Comment: Hi Again. How can I modify the above to Add a single usergroup to every folder within a document library. TIA

Comment: The same way but iterate all folders in library like in this example http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92622/how-to-iterate-through-all-folders-inside-subfolders-of-root-level-folders

Comment: Yep seems like the only way to do anything with sharepoint powershell is find one-off stuff people have done like this. wonderful job.