# PowerShell to grant document library folder permissions

Tags: permissions, content-type, custom, folder

In trying to discover how to grant a group permission on a document library folder I came upon the following StackExchange article:

[Add Group to Folder in a Document Library using Powershell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/109840/add-group-to-folder-in-a-document-library-using-powershell)

I have implemented a "test" version for my purposes before applying it to my code.

```
function Add-SPPermissionToFolderGroup
{
    param ( $Site, $CommitteeSite, $SourceFolder, $GroupName, $PermissionLevel )

    #$sourceFolderGets the folder that is located at the specified URL.
    $Folder = $CommitteeSite.GetFolder( $SourceFolder )
    $Group = $Site.SiteGroups[$GroupName]
    $RoleAssignment = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($Group)
    $RoleDefinition = $Site.RoleDefinitions[$PermissionLevel];

    https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/109840/add-group-to-folder-in-a-document-library-using-powershell

    #break role inheritance for folders/files because they will be having permissions separate from their parent file/folder
    $Folder.Item.BreakRoleInheritance($true);

    #apply the new roleassignment to the folder.  You can do this at the listitem level if desired (i.e. this could be SPfile.Item.... instead of SPFolder.Item)
    $Folder.Item.RoleAssignments.Add($RoleAssignment);
    $Folder.Item.Update();
}

$Site = Get-SPWeb "https://SiteCollectionURL/"
$CommitteeSite = Get-SPWeb "https://SiteCollectionURL/Committees"
$CommitteeLib = "Committees"
$Library = $CommitteeSite.Lists[$CommitteeLib]
Add-SPPermissionToFolderGroup $Site $CommitteeSite "TRAINING_Training" "SP_TRAINING_Managers" "Contribute"
```

When I execute this I get an issue at line 12:

> **You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At line:12 char:5
>   +     $Folder.Item.BreakRoleInheritance($true);
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull**

I get similar issue when trying to run the code below to change the Folders' content type to "Committee"

```
$CommitteeLib = "Committees"
$Library = $CommitteeSite.Lists[$CommitteeLib]
$LibraryCT = $Library.ContentTypes["Committee"]
$SpFolder = $CommitteeSite.GetFolder( "Committees/Test Folder" )
$Item = $SpFolder.Item
$Item["Content Type ID"] = $LibraryCT.ID
$Itemp.Update()
```

The issue occurs in the second last line, and then the error is a null valued $Item.

Any ideas on  where I'm going wrong.

Many thanks.

Dan

Answer (score 0):

It is on the Item itself, not on the folder--my mistake. But the error you are getting suggests that the folder cannot be found, or is in the wrong format. Check to see if the Folder is present. Make sure `$SourceFolder` is a correct value.

This is not returning anything.

```
 $Folder = $CommitteeSite.GetFolder( $SourceFolder )
```

The `$SourceFolder` should be in the format of the site relative url. so try this instead.

```
Add-SPPermissionToFolderGroup $Site $CommitteeSite "/Committees/TRAINING_Training" "SP_TRAINING_Managers" "Contribute"
```

Comment: I tried to break inheritance on the folder as you suggested, but got the following error... Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFolder] does not contain a method named 'BreakRoleInheritance'.

Comment: Check my update.

Comment: Hi Mike. Many thanks for your input. I tried your suggestion but got the same result.

Comment: Just realized that your script doesn't include the library. If the library and the site name are the same, it should really be `$SpFolder = $CommitteeSite.GetFolder( "/Committees/Committee/Test Folder" )`, does `$SpFolder` have any value?

Comment: Hi Mike. Many thanks for your input. I 've  tried your latest suggestion and get the same result. And yes $SpFolder does get a value, but $SpFolder.Item has no value.