# Sharepoint 2010: How to give someone access permissions to a list, including all its elements with unique permissions?

Tags: 2010, permissions, inheritance, unique-permissions

There is a Sharepoint site that has a list with lots of different subfolders, many of which have unique permissions, so that they don't inherit them from the parent list.

I need to give someone permissions to the list and all its subfolders, including the ones with unique permissions.

Is there an automatic way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have broken the inheritance on folders and sub folders then there is no automatic way to give the permissions on list, items, folders and sub folders at a time.

You can create a group and give permission to the group on all elements. So that whenever any new member needs to be given permissions on all element, that time you can add him/her in that group.

Also Note that Site collection administrator can access such folders and sub folders even if the inheritance is broken. You can check more about it [here](https://www.premierpointsolutions.com/training/help-and-how-to-articles/what-is-a-sharepoint-site-collection-administrator/).

**Update from Comments**:

I don't have ready-made PowerShell script. But I found below similar questions as per your requirements:

1. [how to iterate through all folders inside subfolders of root level folders](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92622/how-to-iterate-through-all-folders-inside-subfolders-of-root-level-folders).
2. [SharePoint PowerShell Grant Permission for each subfolders under a specific folder](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/244128/sharepoint-powershell-grant-permission-for-each-subfolders-under-a-specific-fold).

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Yes, the inheritance is broken for all these folders with unique permissions. I also wonder, maybe it would be possible to create a powershell script that recursively goes through all folders and adds the required permission? Although I don't really know much about Sharepoint scripting, so I have no idea.

Comment: Yes, I guess you can automate that using PowerShell script. please check the links provided in updated answer.

Comment: That looks useful! Thank you very much